# How can i get the data from localstorage and view in table using javascript and make a dropdown to sort the table

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following code that need to display the id,name and occupation. i can add to local storage but need to display it in table and sort based on name, id and occupation. any idea how can i do it using javascript. sample output[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV1Zz.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sorting Test</title>
<body>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Add participant<legend>
  <input id="userID" type="text">
  <input id="userName" type="text">
  <input id="userOccupation" type="text">
  <button id="addbtn" type="button" >Add</button>
 </fieldset>
    <br>   
        <div id="displayOutput">           
        </div>        
</body>
<script>
 // get the userid, userName and UserOccupation
 const userID = document.getElementById("userID");
 const userName = document.getElementById("userName");
 const userOccupation = document.getElementById("userOccupation");
 const addbtn = document.getElementById("addbtn");
    const displayOutput = document.getElementById("displayOutput");
 
 //add user input to storage
 addbtn.onclick = function(){
        const id = userID.value;
        const name = userName.value;
        const occupation = userOccupation.value;
        if(id && name && occupation)
        { 
            let myObj = {
                id,
                name,
                occupation
            };
            let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(myObj);
            localStorage.setItem("myObj",myObj_serialized);
        }

        
        //view the stored information
        for (let i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
            {
                
                
                const key = localStorage.key(i);
                const value =localStorage.getItem(key);
                var row = `<tr><td>${key}: ${value}<td><tr><br/>`;        
                displayOutput.innerHTML += row;
                console.log(value);
                
            }      
 }; 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: localStorage only stores string values. in order to store an array of data, you will have to take it and put it through `JSON.stringify()` to store it. To undo the process, you must retrieve the value from localStorage and then run it through `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the stored item values everytime you call setItem. If you want to display a table, I suggest storing an array of objects. If you want to use local storage, Stringify the array before storing and parse it when you need to read it

```
var storeData = function(data) {
    localStorage.setItem("tableData",JSON.stringify(data);
}
storeData([]);

var getData = function() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tableData"));
}
```

And call something like this to save data:

```
storeData(getData().push({id: id, name: name, occupation: occupation});
```

And then to display the data you can do:

```
var arr = getData();
arr.forEach(element) {
    displayOutput.innerHtml += `
        <tr>
        <td>ID: ${element.id}</td>
        <td>Name: ${element.name}</td>
        <td>Occupation: ${element.occupation}</td>
        </tr>`;
}
```

As for the sorting, you can call a sort function on the array on the onclick of the table's column header.